# How to make Cypress use test files located outside of default integration folder?

Tags: testing, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-configuration

I am trying to keep my `**.spec.js` files for testing next to the actual files that need to be tested like such:

```
.
├── product
|   ├── product.js
|   ├── product.spec.js
├── user
|   ├── user.js
|   ├── user.spec.js
```

The above `*.spec.js` files don't appear in the cypress test runner window and I can't find out how to add them.

It only the displays the contents of the `./cypress/integration` folder which contains the example tests included by cypress.

I know you can change the [configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files) of Cypress to look at a different default folder (other than `cypress/integrations`) for tests but my `*.spec.js` files are spread across several different folders.

Is is possible to have cypress test files in different folders and appear in the GUI test runner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the configuration file `cypress.json`, add (for example)

```js
{
  ...
  "integrationFolder": ".",
  "testFiles": ["cypress/integration/**/*.spec.js", "src/**/*.test.js"]
}
```

`integrationFolder: "."` designates the project root to start scan for test files.

But be careful, can pick up tests in `node_modules`, so use an array of locations in the `testFiles` option to indicate folders that have valid tests for your project.

Comment: doesn't work. says can't find `.spec`

Comment: Chovy do you even have a `.spec.js`? Obviously it needs to have precise extensions.

Comment: I ch aged it to .test.js andbit still is looking for spec I guess.

Answer (score 1):

in v13.3.0 (and probably from version 10+), config is in the **cypress.config.js**, in the repo's root.

this, with added **specPattern** line, should work for you:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  component: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    specPattern: '**/*.spec.js',
  },
});
```

any file(s) in entire repo (including sub-direrctories), with extensions **.spec.js**, should match now.

official documentation for component tests:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#component

( i had similar problem, but for end-2-end tests and solution is on the QA/Test portal:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/cypress-js-how-to-change-default-path-for-your-e2e-tests )

Answer (score -2):

Why not delete the example tests/folder inside the integration folder and put yours instead?

```
integration
 ├── product
 |   ├── product.js
 |   ├── product.spec.js
 ├── user
 |   ├── user.js
 |   ├── user.spec.js
```

Comment: The idea is the `spec.js` files should be together with the file to be tested. If they are in separate folders its hard to cross-reference. Some guidance here https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-project-structure-tutorial