# ReferenceError: context is not defined when using cypress with testing-library.com

Tags: node.js, cypress, testing-library

Here's my test in `./tests/homepage.test.js`

```js
context('Signup flow', () => {
    it('The happy path should work', () => {
        cy.visit('https://grazily.com/register');
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
        cy.get('[data-testid=username]').type(`Tester${random}`);
        cy.get('[data-testid=email]').type(`user+${random}@realworld.io`);
        cy.get('[data-testid=password]').type('mysupersecretpassword');
        cy.get('[data-testid=signup-button]').click();
        cy.get('[data-testid=no-articles-here]', { timeout: 10000 }).should('be.visible');
```

Here's the file `./cypress/support/commands.js`

```js
import '@testing-library/cypress/add-commands';
```

tsconfig.json:

```js
"compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"],
...
}
```

I didn't make any other changes...and get this error when running `npm t`

I think `t` uses `jest ./src` so I'm not sure how to invoke cypress in `./tests/*test.js` folder

Update:

```js
Your pluginsFile is invalid: /home/ettinger/src/oblivion/Catalyze-frontend/cypress/plugins/index.js
```

Getting this error now with `cypress run test`

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, `npm t` runs a predefined command specified in the "test" property of a package's "scripts" object.

```js
//package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

so you can either change "jest" to "cypress run" or add extra scripts, for example

```js
//package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "e2e": "cypress run",
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
  }
}
```

or just run "npx cypress open" instead of "npm t".

BTW `context(...)` is valid in a Cypress test.

Comment: Do you know what I should put in `cypress.json`? It fails saying file doesn't exist.

Comment: `Your pluginsFile is invalid: /home/user/src/frontend/cypress/plugins/index.js` -- i don't have this file.

Comment: If you install Cypress and run it (`npx cypress open`), it set's up both (empty) `cypress.json` and all requisite folders and files under `/home/user/src/frontend/cypress`.

Comment: how to i tell it to look in `./tests/**/*.test.js` path? I got it working but it seems to be using TODO MVC code which is in ./cypress/ somewhere.

Comment: nevermind. i see it has a recommended folder layout. I'll just stick with that.

Comment: You're looking for [How to make Cypress use test files located outside of default integration folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816653/how-to-make-cypress-use-test-files-located-outside-of-default-integration-folder)

Answer (score 0):

***Getting this error now with cypress run test***

If you are trying to run a specific test, add `--spec`

```js
npm run cypress run --spec my-test.spec.js
```